# Terraform remote state backend error - Blob Lease Id missing

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-networking, system-state, blob-storage

I am trying to update the remote state file in Azure. Once the blob is created, then when I run terraform apply - I get the following error:

This is the error:

```
* azurerm_storage_blob.testsb: Error setting properties of blob dev.terraform.tfstate (container tfstate, storage account acctestaccs): storage: service returned error: StatusCode=412, ErrorCode=LeaseIdMissing, ErrorMessage=There is currently a lease on the blob and no lease ID was specified in the request.
RequestId:7befe65c-601e-00ba-60e0-cb868c000000
Time:2019-02-24T01:33:46.3387895Z, RequestInitiated=Sun, 24 Feb 2019 01:33:45 GMT, RequestId=7befe65c-601e-00ba-60e0-cb868c000000, API Version=2016-05-31, QueryParameterName=, QueryParameterValue=
```

---

However, I don't have any lease on that blob but still while running in terraform the file shows that the container has been leased and please the lease ID is missing.

I have even tried to use force-unlock but it doesn't work.

Please help me if anyone has a clue on how can this be made working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with the lease. The issue was that I was creating the container in the blob through the code itself. However, blobs automatically create it, we just have to pass the name of the container.